# SQL Server subscriber by IP Address

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a subscriber for SQL Server using IP Address.

The subscriber SQL Server is a in different network, there is a proxy server that forward the port 1433, however now I cannot use the IP address.

The error message is

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a
>   connection to the server. Specify the actual server name

What is the solution?

Comment: Why can't you use the IP address? Do you get an error? Can you connect using that IP address through SSMS (or ODBC or UDL)? Can you ping the IP address? Can you telnet to the port? First do some basic network tests and post the error

Comment: You can't replicate by IP address. You must use the actual server name (it doesn't need to be fully qualified). You can manually create an entry in `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on the publisher that resolves the server name to the proxy server (or you can use a DNS-based solution if the networks are completely separated).

Comment: We can create a subscriber for SQL Server using IP Address in SQL Server 2019 CU14 and above. I test it on domain.

Answer (score 0):

actualy you cannot use ip for Replication, but dont worry, just follow my solution

1- go to this address (%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) and open 'host' file with notepad

2-add your destination Ip with your optional address at end of this file as like as this:

> 5.236.19.251 ecustomersystem.com

3-save your file

now you can user 'ecustomersystem.com' instead of your IP.

this solution worked for me